# HTTP request with Python : TypeError: an integer is required (got type dict)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I was scraping a secured website for my practice project but while doing so I faced this error:

```
sock.settimeout(timeout)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type dict)
```

My code is-

```
>> import urllib.request

>>> import bs4

>>> from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

>>> headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

>>> my_url = uReq('https://www.justdial.com/Mumbai/311/B2b_fil', None, headers)
```

The whole error I got is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 526, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 544, in _open
'_open', req)
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1361, in https_open
context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1318, in do_open
encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "C:\Users\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1239, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 964, in send
self.connect()
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1392, in connect
super().connect()
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 936, in connect
(self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\socket.py", line 710, in create_connection
sock.settimeout(timeout)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type dict)
```

Comment: is requests not an option to use? its easier and more friendly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module instead it would be easier like below.

```
import bs4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
my_url = requests.get('https://www.justdial.com/Mumbai/311/B2b_fil', headers=headers)
```

If you really want to use the urllib, then it would be something below

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

request = Request('http://api.company.com/items/details?country=US&language=en')
request.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36')
response = urlopen(request).read()
```

Comment: @johnll thank you so much for your response it totally worked for me.

Comment: @prashantdhyani - glad to help, you can accept this answer so someone can benefit as well thanks

Comment: @johnll  would u tell me please how to accept this answer ,as i m new to this site .

Comment: @prashantdhyani you can refer to this information https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Create request before sending.Please look at the solution.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib

def main():

    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}    
    url = 'https://www.justdial.com/Mumbai/311/B2b_fil'
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, None, headers)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    print(response.read())
    #my_url = uReq(url, None, headers)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: thank you so much for your response it totally worked for me.